# Resolver algo sobre sql server de poder hacer los datos decimal pero no me cambian

Tags: sql-server

queria saber si alguien me puede ayudar con el siguiente problema en sql server:

Quiero hacer uno de sus columnas me salgan decimla y intente cambiar las variable de entero a decimal y hasta viceversa pero no sucede nada, solo me da 0 en el resultado cuando divido.

```
/* este codigo es el que da el resultado de los 750*/

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tEncuesta WHERE lIdtplPregunta = 1


/*este codigo es el de la cantidad mencionanda de la encuestas*/

select  me.cNombreMedio, COUNT(relmei.lIdtplEncuestaMedio)
from tRelEncuestaMedio as relmei
inner join tMedio as me on relmei.lIdtplMedio = me.lIdtplMedio 
inner join tEncuesta as en on relmei.lIdtplEncuesta = en.lIdtplEncuesta 
inner join tPregunta as pre on en.lIdtplPregunta = pre.lIdtplPregunta
GROUP BY cNombreMedio

/*este es la division que se debe hacer entre la cantidad total de personas (750) y la mencion de la columna que no tiene nombre*/

select  me.cNombreMedio, COUNT(relmei.lIdtplEncuestaMedio),(COUNT(relmei.lIdtplEncuestaMedio)/(SELECT count(*) FROM tencuesta WHERE lidtplPregunta = 1))
from tRelEncuestaMedio as relmei
inner join tMedio as me on relmei.lIdtplMedio = me.lIdtplMedio
GROUP BY cNombreMedio


Si alguien tiene la respuesta. Muchas gracias.
```

Comment: Podrias decirme que numero estas tratando de dividir es decir los numeros que te dan las consultas entiendo que la primera 750 y la otra?

Comment: Bueno en este casi se devidiria el por ejemplos los numeros de la columna que llamaremos menciones. Que seria por ejemplo en la columna: 3/750, 9/750, 234/750, etc; y que se luego esos numero se multipliquen por 100. Que lo que buscos es el porcentaje.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una división de 2 enteros siempre regresará un valor entero con los decimales truncados. Para corregirlo, necesitas convertir uno de los valores en un tipo de dato que acepte decimales (decimal, numeric o float).

```
SELECT  me.cNombreMedio, 
    COUNT(relmei.lIdtplEncuestaMedio),
    CAST(COUNT(relmei.lIdtplEncuestaMedio) AS decimal(18, 4))/(SELECT count(*) FROM tencuesta WHERE lidtplPregunta = 1)
FROM tRelEncuestaMedio as relmei
INNER JOIN tMedio as me on relmei.lIdtplMedio = me.lIdtplMedio
GROUP BY cNombreMedio;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, eso es lo que necesitaba. De verdad gracias.